# Bone constraints makes the animation act like a rag doll

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, constraints

[image]

You can see it for example in the DualsCombo_1 animation between Frame 10 and 30. (And all other fast moving animations)

i added constraints,stretch to, rotate to, etc. to simulate a muscle behavior in my animations. The problem is that the animation, with fast movements, behaves like a jiggling rag doll. The head drags behind while rotating. Can anyone explain why does it happens and how to avoid it?

Kind regards

Comment: Please share your blend file, with an animation showing the problem. (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice :) I will do

Comment: It sounds like a dependency loop.  Open a console view (main window menu) and look for "dependency cycle warnings".  If you find any, use the message to help guide you to where you made an accidental loop.